# Grunt not running on Windows 8

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, windows-8.1

I got the following message when I try to run grunt:

> grunt
>   'grunt' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
>   ou externe, un programme exécutable ou un fichier de commandes.

(using google translate)

> grunt 'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

My computer is new, I just installed node.js on it, with windows 8. Maybe I missed something?

I have grunt and other grunt-contrib in my node_modules folder. So I don't undertsand the issue here ^^ DO you have any idea? (I got no error on the shell when I installed it)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Install the grunt-cli command globally with: `npm install grunt-cli -g`

Comment: Thanks! I just I have to go to sleep... ^^'